# Using Multiple GPUs with C++ cntk

Tags: c++, cntk

I'm trying to gradually move over from brainscript to the C++ interface for cntk. The complete lack of documentation doesn't help. My latest project is multi-gpu training. There's an example for single GPU training. What is the best strategy for doing multi-gpu training. Is there a c++ equivalent of the python data_parallel_distributed_learner? (or other parallelisation methods) or do you have to code it yourself at the low level (data selection, model parameter combination, etc.). How does this work with MPI? Is threads/OpenMP an option as with evaluation (in whch case how to select the GPU/combine distributed models).

Answer (score 0):

The Python APIs are mostly following the C++ APIs. So if you understand how to train on multiple GPUs with Python, the C++ is a straight translation from Python. For distributed training you will need 
`CreateDataParallelDistributedLearner`, and to specify the number of workers in the `MinibatchSource` constructor as well as make sure every worker reads a different part of the data as can be done by the `workerRank` argument of `GetNextMinibatch`. As with Python you will need an MPI implementation and to invoke your C++ program with mpirun.